Programmatically upload asset to Content Hub with field values and Final Lifecycle status
I'm trying to upload images to Content Hub using a PowerShell 7 script. The script executes as expected and the image is uploaded.

I want to also pass a few field values like Type (Radio Button), Restricted Access (Checkboxes) in the script.
Currently, the asset gets uploaded with the Final Lifecycle Status as Created. Is it possible to set it to Approved, in the script.

Please suggest, how to achieve the 2 tasks.

PS Script:
Clear-Host

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http

$authToken = "Bearer  abc"
$hostName = "https://xyz.cloud"

$fileName = "test_upload_1.png"
$filePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\test_upload_1.png"
$fileSize = 4096

# create request
$createAssetBody = @{
    file_name            = $fileName
    file_size            = $fileSize
    upload_configuration = @{
        name = "AssetUploadConfiguration"
    }
    action               = @{
        name = "NewAsset"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
$createUrl = $hostName + "/api/v2.0/upload"
$createResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $createUrl -Method 'POST' -Body $createAssetBody -Headers @{"Authorization" = $authToken; "Content-Type" = "application/json" }

# upload request
if ($createResponse.Headers.ContainsKey('Location')) {
    $uploadUrl = [string]$createResponse.Headers.Location    
}
else {    
    Write-Error "The response does not contain a 'Location' header."    
    exit    
}

$fileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$fileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new('form-data')
$fileHeader.Name = $fileName
$fileHeader.FileName = Split-Path -leaf $filePath
$fileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($fileStream)
$fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $fileHeader
$fileContent.Headers.ContentType = [System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue]::Parse("text/plain")
$multipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$multipartContent.Add($fileContent)
Invoke-WebRequest -Body $multipartContent -Method 'POST' -Uri $uploadUrl -Headers @{"Authorization" = $authToken }
$fileStream.Close()
# finalize request
$finalizeUrl = $hostName + "/api/v2.0/upload/finalize"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $finalizeUrl -Method 'POST' -Body $createResponse.Content -Headers @{"Authorization" = $authToken; "Content-Type" = "application/json" }


The finalize call will return you the asset id uploaded in Sitecore Content Hub using the above Powershell snippet. Thereafter using the asset id, you can use below REST API to update relational properties.
PUT: {{CH_TenantURL}}//api/entities/{{Entity_ID}}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Request Payload:

{
    "properties": {
        "Title": "{{UpdatedTitle}}"  
    },
    "relations": {
        "AssetTypeToAsset": {
            "parent": {
                "href": "{{CH_TenantURL}}/api/entities/{{AssetTypeID}}"
            }
        },
        "FinalLifeCycleStatusToAsset": {
            "parent": {
                "href": "{{CH_TenantURL}}/api/entities/{{ApprovedID}}"
            }
        }
    },
    "entitydefinition": {
        "href":"/api/entitydefinitions/M.Asset"
    }
}

Using above way, you can modify the relational properties such as FinalLifeCycleStatusToAsset and AssetTypeToAsset. Through some way, you can modify other properties as well.
Note: Above API requires bearer token for authentication. You can generate the token for the tenant by following Sitecore documentation link.
Update:
You can use below P.S snippet to update the asset properties and relations.
$tenantUrl = "{{CH_TenantURL}}"
$accessToken = "{{AccessToken}}"
$entityID = "{{AssetID}}"
$approvedID = "{{LifecycleStatusApprovedID}}"
$assetTypeID = "{{AssetTypeID}}"
$title = "{{Title}}"

$entityUpdateUrl = "$tenantUrl/api/entities/$entityID"
Write-Host "Entity Update API Url: $entityUpdateUrl"
    
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}

$body = @{
    "properties" = @{
        "Title" = "$title"  
    }
    "relations" = @{
        "AssetTypeToAsset" = @{
            "parent" = @{
                "href" = "$tenantUrl/api/entities/$assetTypeID"
            }
        }
        "FinalLifeCycleStatusToAsset" = @{
            "parent" =  @{
                "href" = "$tenantUrl/api/entities/$approvedID"
            }
        }
    }
    "entitydefinition" = @{
        "href" = "/api/entitydefinitions/M.Asset"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

Write-Host $body

$contentType = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
    
try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $entityUpdateUrl -Method Put -Body $body -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType
    if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) {
         Write-Host "Entity has been updated successfully"
    } 
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error occurred while updating entity $($_.Exception.Message)"
    return $null
}

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Is there a PowerShell version to this?

@sukesh you can check one of my blogs https://sitecorefoundation.wordpress.com/2024/10/21/migrating-assets-in-sitecore-content-hub/ which gives details on how to fetch access token using PS snippet and call the api/entities endpoint. Let me know in case you face any issues.

No, I know how to get the access token. I'm referring to passing details in the powershell script.

@sukesh by details you are referring to?

I would like to set the asset properties and also the lifecycle status in the same powershell script.

@sukesh I have added the P.S code above to update the asset properties and relations. Let me know in case you have any queries.

You will get the assetid from the finalize api response. You can fetch that asset id and pass in the above code snippet.
